# How can i transform icon in font-icon

Tags: css, svg, fonts, icons

I have one icon made by me using illustrator and I want to turn it into an icon-font and declare it as a fontawsome:   not with svg.
How can I do this?

Comment: There is very lovely free app called icon moon you can use it to create your own custom icon font from svg files. Very maintainable and editable in future with config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very lovely free app called icon moon you can use it to create your own custom icon font from svg files. Very maintainable and editable in future with config file.

https://icomoon.io/app/#/select